# Bootstrap - navbar doesn't work on all screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new and I don't speak english very good but I think that You can understand me and help :). I just started my adventure with bootstrap. 
So... my navbar when has only 4 /li/ work with all screen sizes.
Here is the code:

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <!-- navbar-brand is hidden on larger screens, but visible when the menu is collapsed -->
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Business Casual</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="about.html">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="blog.html">Blog</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

But the problem is when I modify navbar and add for example 2 more /li/ like this:

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default " role="navigation">
<div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Health</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Main menu</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#>Doctors</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Presciprions</a>
            </li>
            @if(Auth::check())
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Panel</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Logout</a>
                </li>
            @else
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Login</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Register</a>
                </li>
            @endif
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div>
<!-- /.container -->
```

My navbar is not responsive with screen between 768 and 992 / and / 992 and 1200. I think, because It doesnt work on Tablets and my navbar is curling - I would like to be always on one line, no matter witch size screen is. Where is my mistake?

[**Link to page**](http://serwer1623658.home.pl/laravel/blog/public/przychodnia)

Comment: Do you have link access to your url ?

Comment: you have to reduce the padding for `.nav > li > a` in that width range using media query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add this code to your custom file css

```
@media screen (min-width: 768px) and (max-width:1200){
   .nav>li>a {
    padding: 36px 5px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow It really works, but is there a possibility to make some spaces between links in navbar? Because now they looks like there's no spaces between them.  I see thaht It works onlu with 5px padding, cause when I add more then my problem with curling navbar come back. And is possibility to explain me why it work now with 5px? Just a little?

Comment: Ok don't forget mart as answer! I will have look for you

Comment: Update css: padding: 36px 15px; and then udpate media screen: @media screen (min-width: 768px) and (max-width:992px){

Comment: this one for ipad screen add below code above 
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
.nav>li>a {
    padding: 36px 5px;
}

}

Comment: Kristoff thank You for helping me :) All works now and I know why :) Thanks one more time!